# No packages installed in ros/fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am completely new to ROS and am just trying to get up and running.

I am on a Mac computer running a VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed the [instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) to install ROS and everything went fine.

Then, I moved on to the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), and everything went fine until I tried to create a new workspace.

When I ran the command `rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte` I got the error message

`Using ROS_ROOT: /opt/ros/fuerte`

`ERROR in config: Is not a local file, nor a valid URL [/opt/ros/fuerte] : unknown url type: /opt/ros/fuerte`

I just checked the folder `/opt/ros/` and the only folder in it is `kinetic`. There is no `fuerte` folder in `/opt/ros/`.

What can I do to solve this issue?

EDIT:

I discovered why I was confused.

I was using the new "Reader View" mode on Firefox, which displays both versions of creating a workspace without differentiating between the two.

Tip to self: Don't use "Reader View" when trying to follow important instructions.

(I'm new to Firefox, so I had no idea it would change how the page looked that much.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259229/no-packages-installed-in-ros/fuerte/) by [Jadiker](https://answers.ros.org/users/30019/jadiker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are new to ROS you might not be familiar with its history. The version that you installed in your virtual machine is ROS Kinetic (The current recommended version).

In this distribution the build system is called "catkin", in older ROS versions (like Fuerte) the build system was called "rosbuild" and it is not used any more, but the documentation is still available.

If you pay attention, in certain sections of the tutorials, you can chose between "caktin" and "rosbuild" instructions. Make sure that you follow "catkin" instructions. From the command that you posted it seems that you are following the instructions for "rosbuild".

I hope this helps.
Welcome to ROS

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4